# Silverlight error + Cannot perform runtime binding on null reference

Tags: silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

In my crm application , i have an old silverlight webresource in the form of a grid which sets data in a field on the form.

However when the record is created freshly, and if the user adds data into the silverlight grid, while setting value in the crm field, it throws the error as "Cannot perform runtime binding on Null reference"

Below is the line at which it throws the error .

```
  dynamic att = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_crmfield");
```

As per my understanding , it does not find the field at first, however how do i resolve this.

Please suggest.

Comment: Try with `parent.Xrm`

Comment: Is 'new_crmfield' a new Row on the fly? Check where that element is getting added (in memory), I think it is not getting memory allocated which is why it throws error when u r adding the row...